# How as one ImageView show different pictures?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a controller in which there are various questions and images.

In each question all the elements (images, button) are shifted relative to the size of the text. But I also have pictures of different sizes. How as one ImageView show pictures of different size correctly, so that they adjust to the screen?

I use Interface Builder. Can I submit the coordinates in Interface Builder. A resize software programmatically?

Comment: please give an image for clarify

Comment: it depends on how you customise your imageview each time. You may choose asspectfit for some images, aspectfill for some. Please clarify

Comment: Pictures in a ImageView have a different aspect ratio. But placing ImageView depends on the size of the text. From text it is always located at 30px .

Comment: This can help you. http://jacksonkr.com/content/uiimageview-scaling-explained-visually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily as long as you don't have images inline with your text. You can set these up in Interface Builder and use AutoLayout. Set constraints from your image to the bottom of your text and they will move.

Example:

```
Image is not inline w/ text so easy to set up constraints.
__________
|         |
|  <img>  |
|_________|
texttextextextexttext


Image is inline w/ text so not easy to set up constraints for resizing

texttexttext _____________
texttextte   |           |
textextextt  |   <IMG>   |
textextexte  |___________|
textextextextextextextexte
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do it in code.